# Python : Regex search on a file, and another regex in the next line

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to search for a particular string in every line of a log file, and if that matches, i need to be able to get the Host information from that particular error.

Consider the log entries as below :

```
05-05-2014 00:02:02,771 [HttpProxyServer-thread-1314] ERROR fd - Empty user name specified in NTLM authentication. Prompting for auth again.
Host=tools.google.com, Port=80, Client ip=/10.253.168.128, port=37271, User-Agent: Google Update/1.3.23.9;winhttp;cup-ecdsa
05-05-2014 00:02:02,771 [HttpProxyServer-thread-2156] ERROR fd - Empty user name specified in NTLM authentication. Prompting for auth again.
Host=tools.google.com, Port=80, Client ip=/10.253.168.148, port=37273, User-Agent: Google Update/1.3.23.9;winhttp;cup-ecdsa
05-05-2014 00:02:02,802 [HttpProxyServer-thread-604] ERROR fd - Empty user name specified in NTLM authentication. Prompting for auth again.
Host=tools.google.com, Port=80, Client ip=/10.253.168.92, port=37280, User-Agent: Google Update/1.3.23.9;winhttp;cup
```

This is my code :

```
for line in log_file:

   if bool(re.search( r'Empty user name specified in NTLM authentication. Prompting for auth again.', line)):

   host = re.search(r'Host=(\D+.\D+.\D+,)', line).group(1)
```

Problem is the Host information is not in the same line as the error. It is in the next line. How do i get the re.search(r'Host=(\D+.\D+.\D+,)', line).group(1) to search in the next line that "line" is currently in?

Comment: What's wrong with reading the whole file?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, perhaps, that huge log files need not comfortably fit in memory...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> import re
>>> fp = open('log_file')
>>> line = fp.readline()
>>> while line:
...    if 'Empty user name specified in NTLM authentication. Prompting for auth again.' in line:
...        host = re.search(r'Host=(\D+.\D+.\D+,)', fp.readline()).group(1)
...        #                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
...        #                              this makes re search in the next line 
...        print host
...    line = fp.readline()
... 
tools.google.com,
tools.google.com,
tools.google.com,
```

Comment: Irshad! Worked like a freakin charm! But how did the contents of "line" get changed to the next line? Does that happen with the While statement?

Comment: See first line is read outside `while`. Now if this line contains **Empty user .... auth again.** , `re` searches in the next line using `fp.readline()` in `host = re.search(r'Host=(\D+.\D+.\D+,)', fp.readline()).group(1)`. After that last code line in `while` i.e., `line = fp.readline()` reads next line and proceeds again with `while`.

Answer (score 2):

Just insert a

```
line = next(log_file)
```

between the two statements you currently have in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Either write a regex that matches 2 successive lines from which you can extract the Host info of each, and loop over the matches instead of reading the file line-by-line, or add a flag that gets set when a line matches the error, and if that flag is set for a given line, you extract the host info & reset the flag instead of testing for the error.